# Check if a element is on the actual page

Tags: javascript, jquery, element, visibility

I'm using a [poshytip](http://vadikom.com/demos/poshytip/), it is working fine, until I want to display my tip on the element that is *under* the current page (I mean that page where I have to scroll down to see it, don't really know how to name it properly). Unfortunately, poshytip has some bugs related to that - if I want to display a tip on the element that is currently lower than the current page position, then tip is showing at the bottom of my page. Havent seen any better tip plugin than this, so I decided to fix it on my own.

The question is - is there a way in jQuery/javascript to check if the element (for example the input with ID) is on the current page that user is viewing? By saying `current page` I mean the top of the page - my element is placed much lower, so user have to scroll down the page to see it, so is there a way to do something like: if user is scrolling down the page, and the element will be finally *visible* then send alert to the user?

I know this may be kinda complicated, but couldn't find any better words to describe my problem, I'd answer additional questions, if you have one.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/jquery-check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: @cubuzoa The function from the marked answer in that question works fine. I think I'll use this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test for an element's visibility `in the viewport`, you should reference this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport) as it's outlined quite clearly.

On another note, I prefer using the jQuery tools suite for my Tooltip plugin of choice. You can see it [here](http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.html)